# A quick way to find the first matching submatrix from the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, comparison

My matrix is simple, like:

```
# python3 numpy
>>> A
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> P
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I need to find an all-zero region(one is enough) in A with the same size as P (1x4).
So the right answer include:

```
(2, 0)  # The vertex coordinates of the all-zero rectangular region that P can be matched
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(4, 0)
(4, 1)
# Just get any 1 answer
```

Actually my A matrix will reach a size of 30,000*30,000. I'm worried that it will be slow if written as a loop statement. Is there any quick way?

The size of P is uncertain, from 10*30 to 4000*80. At the same time, the A matrix lacks regularity, and looping from any point may require traversing the entire matrix to successfully match

Comment: My assumption is it would depend how likely / dense you expect the matches to exist. I believe (not entirely sure about that) any vectorized code in numpy will compute over the entire matrix. So the looping will be numpy fast but it won't exit as soon as the first solution is found. If you write your loop in python, it will likely be slower, but then you can easily exist early.

Comment: Will `P` always have this size and shape, or do you need to generalize for that as well?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel not always

Comment: @Julien If there is a numpy method that works, I can compare it with the loop. Because in fact, there are a large number of cases of upper-left matching and bottom-right matching. No matter where you start the cycle, you can run into the worst

Comment: How large may the matrix `P` reach? In your example the matrix has only 0 or 1, is it the same for your actual matrix?

Comment: @ken The specific can not be determined, 10*20~3000*80~4000*3000 or larger is possible. But it does not exceed the dimensions of A

Comment: `np.where((np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(A, P.shape) == P).all(axis=tuple(range(-len(P.shape),0))))` works at least for small enough arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Julien pointed out in the comment, in general, we can use sliding windows for this kind of task.

```py
def find_all_zero_region_by_sliding_window(a, shape):
    x, y = np.nonzero(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, shape).max(axis=-1).max(axis=-1) == 0)
    return np.stack((x, y), axis=-1)


find_all_zero_region_by_sliding_window(A, P.shape)
```

However, unfortunately, this requires a lot of memory.

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.3 TiB for an array with shape (26001, 29921, 4000) and data type float32
                                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

As an alternative, I think using the [Summed-area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table) is a good idea.

It is similar to the sliding window approach above, but instead of finding the maximum value, we can calculate the sum (very efficiently) and search for the position where it is zero.
Note that this assumes that `A` does not contain any negative values. Otherwise, you would have to use `numpy.abs`.

Since we do not need to be able to calculate the sum of any given position, I adapted this idea and implemented it to require only a single-line cache.

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Tuple


def find_all_zero_region(arr: np.ndarray, kernel_size: Tuple[int, int]) -> np.ndarray:
    input_height, input_width = arr.shape
    kernel_height, kernel_width = kernel_size

    matches = []

    # Calculate summed_line for y==0.
    summed_line = arr[:kernel_height].sum(axis=0)

    for y in range(input_height - kernel_height + 1):
        # Update summed_line for row y.
        if y != 0:  # Except y==0, which already calculated above.
            # Adding new row and subtracting old row.
            summed_line += arr[y + kernel_height - 1] - arr[y - 1]

        # Calculate kernel_sum for (y, 0).
        kernel_sum = summed_line[:kernel_width].sum()
        if kernel_sum == 0:
            matches.append((y, 0))

        # Calculate kernel_sum for (y, 1) to (y, right-edge).
        # Using the idea of a summed-area table, but in 1D (horizontally).
        (all_zero_region_cols,) = np.nonzero(kernel_sum + np.cumsum(summed_line[kernel_width:] - summed_line[:-kernel_width]) == 0)
        for col in all_zero_region_cols:
            matches.append((y, col + 1))

    if not matches:
        # For Numba, output must be a 2d array.
        return np.zeros((0, 2), dtype=np.int64)
    return np.array(matches, dtype=np.int64)
```

As you can see, this uses loops, but it should be much faster than you think because the required memory is relatively small and the number of calculations/comparisons is greatly reduced.
Here is some timing code.

```py
import time


rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
A = rng.integers(0, 2, size=(30000, 30000)).astype(np.float32)

P = np.zeros(shape=(4000, 80))

# Create an all-zero region in the bottom right corner which will be searched last.
A[-P.shape[0] :, -P.shape[1] :] = 0

started = time.perf_counter()
result = find_all_zero_region(A, P.shape)
print(f"{time.perf_counter() - started} sec")
print(result)
# 3.541154200000001 sec
# [[26000 29920]]
```

Moreover, this function can be even faster by using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).
Just add annotations as follows:

```py
import numba


@numba.njit("int64[:,:](float32[:,:],UniTuple(int64,2))")
def find_all_zero_region_with_numba(arr: np.ndarray, kernel_size: Tuple[int, int]) -> np.ndarray:
    ...
```

```py
started = time.perf_counter()
find_all_zero_region_with_numba(A, P.shape)
print(f"{time.perf_counter() - started} sec")
# 1.6005743999999993 sec
```

Note that I implemented it to find all positions of the all-zero regions, but you can also make it return on the first one.
Since it uses loops, the average execution time will be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, analysing entirely `A` can be expensive, especially because `A` is big in memory (so it will fit in RAM) and the RAM is slow. We can **scan `A` line by line** so to find out is `P` can fit in the `np` last lines of `A` where `np,mp = P.shape` and `na,ma = A.shape`. The thing is `np` can be quite big so we need a fast way so check that.

To make the problem simpler to understand, let assume we can (efficiently) pre-compute `B = A == 0`. Now the question is how to find a 2D area of `True` values with a size of at least `(np,mp)`. To do that we can compute the logical AND of the `np` last lines of `B` and check if there are a sequence of at least `mp` values in the result. For example, if `np=3` and `mp=4`, then we can compute `mask = B[i] & B[i+1] & B[i+2]` for each possible `i`, and then check for each `mask` if there is 4 consecutive `True`. This operation is nothing more than a **2D convolution with a logical AND operator** and the above optimization (drastically reducing the *algorithmic complexity*) is called **filter separation**.

In fact, note that the logical AND of boolean numbers is equivalent to a product of 0-1 values. This means we can speed up the convolution using a **2D Fast-Fourier Tranform** (FFT). While 2D FFTs can be used to compute this problem algorithmically optimally (in `O(na ma ((log na) + (log ma)))` time), this require a significant amount of memory, and we cannot combine them with the scan-line strategy. We can find another strategy using less memory at the expense of possibly more computations (and a less optimal complexity).

One can see that the `mask` of consecutive lines mostly compute the same thing, especially when `np` is big. Indeed, for `i=0` we compute `mask = B[0] & B[1] & B[2]`, and for `i=1`, we compute `mask = B[1] & B[2] & B[3]`. `B[1] & B[2]` is recomputed twice. For k consecutive lines, `np-k` terms are shared/re-computed. Thus, if `np` is big, it is better to **factorize the operations** in order not to recompute many terms.

To do that, an efficient approach is to build a **binary-tree containing partial reductions**. For example, we can compute `node0 = B[0] & B[1]` and `node1 = B[2] & B[3]` and then `node2 = node0 & node1`, so then if we want to compute `B[0] & B[1] & B[2]` we can reuse the binary tree nodes. We can show that `O(log np)` node values are enough to compute `mask` (i.e. the intersection of the `np` last lines). This means this solution is efficient (similar to the FFT one). However, it is not simple to implement.

A simpler, less efficient solution, is to compute the intersection of lines by **chunks** of size `c`. `c` needs to be carefully chosen : big enough to avoid recomputing several times the same thing, small enough for chunks to actually be useful. `c = int(ceil(sqrt(np)/2))` is certainly a good solution for relatively big `np` values (not using chunks is certainly better when `np` is very small like `<=4`).

Note you can **pack booleans into bits** so to make the line intersection significantly faster since the resulting arrays are 8 times smaller. This can be done using `np.packbits`. With this strategy, the logical AND of the booleans is replaced by a bit-wise AND (which is as fast if not actually faster). While a line of `A` of length 30_000 require 234 KiB of RAM, the associated booleans can be stored in only 4 KiB. The last can better fit in CPU caches, speeding up the computation.

Note that the computation can be stopped early when a matching scan-line is found. Also please note that if `mp << np`, then it might be significantly faster to first transpose `A`.

For sake of performance, Cython or Numba can be used to compute that efficiently (CPython loops are slow but not the ones of Cython/Numba).

Answer (score 0):

To find coordinates of all zero rectangles of a certain height/width, you can convert the 1s and 0s to the number of consecutive 0s horizontally and compare those to your target width.  Then do the same thing vertically on Trues of the result of the horizontal comparison.  All coordinates that accumulate to your minimal vertical size will represent the bottom-right corner of the zero rectangles:

```
import numpy as np

A = np. array([
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

height,width = 3,2


H0 = (A == 0)*(np.arange(A.shape[1])+1)[None,:]
H1 = (A != 0)*(np.arange(A.shape[1])+1)[None,:]
Hz = H0 - np.maximum.accumulate(H1,axis=1)

V0 = (Hz >= width)*(np.arange(A.shape[0])+1)[:,None]
V1 = (Hz <  width)*(np.arange(A.shape[0])+1)[:,None]
V2 = V0 - np.maximum.accumulate(V1,axis=0)

bottomRight = np.where(V2 >= height)
topLeft     = bottomRight - np.array([[height-1],[width-1]])

print(*zip(*topLeft))
print(*zip(*bottomRight))

(0, 0) (2, 2)
(2, 1) (4, 3)
```

This may be easier to grasp by examining intermediate results:

**Hz** number of consecutive 0s horizontally (1s have negative values)

```
array([[ 1,  2, -3, -4, -5],
       [ 1,  2, -3, -4, -5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 1, -2,  1,  2, -5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
```

*values of 2 (or more) correspond to ending positions of horizontally consecutive zeros that match the width requirement*

**V2** number of vertically consecutive matches of horizontal size (Hz >= width)

```
array([[-1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-2,  2, -2, -2, -2],
       [-3,  3,  1,  1,  1],
       [-4, -4, -4,  2, -4],
       [-5,  1,  1,  3,  1]])
```

*Positions containing 3 (or more) correspond to the bottom right corner of zero rectangles of size 3x2*

**Performance**

This "whole matrix" approach is slow on very large data (30,000 x 30,000 takes 220 seconds).   Since you're only looking for one occurrence, a hybrid vectorize/loop approach might give better results:

```
V2       = np.zeros(A.shape[1])
rowRange = np.arange(A.shape[1])+1
for r,row in enumerate(A==0):
    H0 = row*rowRange
    H1 = (~row)*rowRange
    Hz = (H0 - np.maximum.accumulate(H1)) >= width
    V2 = V2*Hz + Hz
    if np.any(V2>=height):
        print(time()-start,"found",(r,np.where(V2>=height)[0][0]))
        break
```

This hybrid approach uses the same technique but does it row by row instead of on the whole matrix. You could optimize if further if the matrix is not square by choosing to process by column or by row based on the smaller dimension.  Since the Pyhton loop is slower than vectorized numpy calculations, this should minimize the Python code overhead.

On a 30,000 x 30,000 matrix, it only took 9 seconds when NOT finding any match (which is the worst case scenario).  It is not faster on smaller sizes (e.g. 500 x 500) but it does reduce the amount of memory manipulated by numpy and eventually catches up.

In both cases, the speed is independent of the size of P.